# How to include handle days with no delivery?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

I am currently trying to forecast the delivery of cash to branches. The problem I face is that there are a few days, as well as most Sundays, in which there are no deliveries. Hence, in the time series for those dates I have zeroes. I am using a years worth of data for the training set and wish to apply the forecast to the following year. Additionally, it is daily data. The forecast technique I am using is the ARIMA model. I have used the auto.arima function. However, the accuracy I have has been horrible - I am under the impression I am doing something incorrectly. Will the these dates of no deliveries cause an error in the forecast?

Updated:

Using seasonality of one week.

The following is the plot of the time series (actual vs. fitted)

[image]

My assumptions from ACF and PACF is that it is stationary.

I am new to ARIMA forecasting.

Updated with the log of the volumes and na.action=na.pass

[image]

The following is the code used:

```
library(tseries)
library(ggplot2)
library(forecast)
library(readxl)

##Data to time-series and incorporating seasonality
data = ts(Volume,frequency = 7)


##correlograms
acftest = acf(data, na.action = na.pass)
pacftest = pacf(data, na.action = na.pass)

##Arima Forecast
arimaf = auto.arima(data)

#results
resultsfUL= data.frame(cbind(time(Trial_Dataset4log$Date),(Trial_Dataset4log$Volume),(acx)))
names(resultsf) <- c("Date", "Actual", "Fitted")

ggplot(data=resultsfUL, aes(x=Date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y=Actual, colour = "Actual"), size=1.2) +
  geom_line(aes(y=Fitted, colour = "Fitted"), size=1.2, linetype=2)
```

Comment: Do you know something about the delivery days with high amounts? mondays? with low amounts? (except the zeros). Your zeros are known zeros, so do not really belong inn the data. I would try to replace them with NA's (arima functions in R works well with NA's). Also, with so high variability, maybe model the logs. Is what you have shown us data for one btanch only, so you have many such series?

Comment: Thanks for the response. The data I have just has the volume of the amount delivered. Do you mean I should log the volumes first and then forecast? No just this branch

Comment: Does that mean that, for each day, it is the sum of deliveries to all the branches?

Comment: This is actually the sum of multiple deliveries on each day. Therefore, there could have been 4 deliveries to the branch on one day and I just summed that.

Comment: Can you replace zeros with NA's, take logs (maybe base 10), then show us the autocorrelation function?

Comment: I have updated the ACF and PACF .However I had to keep the zeroes for those as the function could not compute NA's.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59884/discussion-between-dr-watcher-and-kjetil-b-halvorsen).